# How to stream to/from a file descriptor in node?

Tags: node.js, stream, file-descriptor, child-process

The `fs.createReadStream()` and `fs.createWriteStream()` only support file *paths* but I need to read (or write) from a file descriptor (passed to/from a child process).

Note I need Streams, so `fs.open/fs.read/fs.write` are not sufficient.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) you can pass in a file descriptor:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fd = fs.openSync('/tmp/tmp.js', 'r');
var s = fs.createReadStream(null, {fd: fd});
s.pipe(process.stdout);
```

If there is a `fd` option, the filename is ignored.

Comment: Excellent! I found the reverse also works, with `fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: fd});`. Weird this is not documented in the manual, but it works like a charm.

Comment: If you stare carefully at the doc I linked to, you see that it's at least hinted at in the docs, although I admit that I found it in the source. :)

Comment: Yea, but all the other fs methods have spceial versions for file descriptors. I did notice the fd param but nothing suggest you could use null as path. Odd that.

Comment: You need to pass empty string like this `fs.createReadStream('', {fd: fd})` instead of `null`.

Comment: LOL "stare carefully"

Answer (score 4):

```
// Open &3:
process.oob1 = fs.createWriteStream(null, { fd: 3 });
// Write to &3 / oob1 (out-of-band 1)
process.oob1.write("Note: this will throw an exception without 3>&1 or something else declaring the existence of &3");
```